# When I refresh the Datatable with JQuery it shows the entire table. (Pagination not working)

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, datatable, datatables

Here is my table code:

```
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="main-body">
                    <?php
                    if ($role == 'FACULTY') : ?>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
                            <div class="card bg-dark text-light">
                                <div class="card-body row p-5 d-flex  justify-content-between">
                                    <div class="col-auto m-auto">
                                        Add a new complaint
                                    </div>
                                    <div class=" col-auto m-auto">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newComplaintModal">
                                            New Complaint
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <!-- Complaint Table -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">History of Complaints</h5>
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="zero_config" class="table table-hover table-bordered text-center">
                                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th><b>S.No</b></th>
                                                <th><b>ID</b></th>
                                                <th><b>Room No</b></th>
                                                <th><b>Details</b></th>
                                                <th><b>Status</b></th>
                                                <?php
                                                if ($role == 'FACULTY') {
                                                    echo '<th><b>Feedback</b></th>';
                                                } ?>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="table-body">
                                            <?php
                                            if ($role == 'MANAGER') {
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM complaints ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                echo "<script>console.log('MANAGER')</script>";
                                            } elseif ($role == 'HOD') {
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE hod_id='$s' ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                echo "<script>console.log('hod')</script>";
                                            } elseif ($role == 'FACULTY') {
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE fac_id='$s' ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                echo "<script>console.log('faculty')</script>";
                                            } elseif ($role == 'GENERAL') {
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE status=2 ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                echo "<script>console.log('faculty')</script>";
                                            } elseif ($role == 'ITKM') {
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE status=3 ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                echo "<script>console.log('faculty')</script>";
                                            } else {
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM complaints  ORDER BY id DESC ";
                                                echo "<script>console.log('others')</script>";
                                            }
                                            $query_run = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                                            if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0) {
                                                $sno = 1;
                                                foreach ($query_run as $complaint) {
                                                    $v = $complaint['status'];
                                                    $statusMessage = '';
                                                    switch ($v) {
                                                        case 0:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'At HOD';
                                                            break;
                                                        case 1:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'At Manager';
                                                            break;
                                                        case 2:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'At Generals';
                                                            break;
                                                        case 3:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'At ITKM';
                                                            break;
                                                        case 4:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'Resolved';
                                                            break;
                                                        case 5:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'Resolved';
                                                            break;
                                                        case 100:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'Cancelled';
                                                            break;
                                                        case -10:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'HOD Rejected';
                                                            break;
                                                        case -9:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'Manager Rejected';
                                                            break;
                                                        default:
                                                            $statusMessage = 'Error';
                                                            break;
                                                    }

                                            ?>
                                                    <tr data-approval="<?= $v ?>">
                                                        <td><?= $sno ?></td>
                                                        <td><?= $complaint['id'] ?></td>
                                                        <td><?= $complaint['place'] ?></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                                                <!-- xxxxx -->
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark border-0 m-auto shadow-sm view-btn" data-id="<?= $complaint['id'] ?>">
                                                                    <span class="ti-eye"></span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                <!-- cancel and edit complaint part-->
                                                                <?php
                                                                if ($complaint['status'] == 0 && $role == 'FACULTY') { ?>
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark border-0 m-auto shadow-sm edit-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editComplaintModal" data-id="<?= $complaint['id'] ?>"><span class="ti-pencil"></span></button>
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cancel-button m-auto shadow-sm" data-id="<?= $complaint['id'] ?>"><span class="ti-close"></span></button>
                                                                <?php }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <!-- end of the cancell part-->
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <?php
                                                            if ($statusMessage == 'Resolved')
                                                                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-auto shadow-sm">' . $statusMessage . '</button>';
                                                            elseif ($statusMessage == 'HOD Rejected' || $statusMessage == 'Cancelled' || $statusMessage == 'Manager Rejected')
                                                                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-auto shadow-sm">' . $statusMessage . '</button>';
                                                            else
                                                                echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-light m-auto shadow-sm">' . $statusMessage . '</button>';
                                                            ?>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <?php
                                                        if ($role == 'FACULTY' && $complaint['feedback'] == NULL && ($complaint['status'] == 4 or $complaint['status'] == 5)) { ?>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <!-- Button to trigger the ComplaintFeedbackmodal -->
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary m-auto shadow-sm border-0 feed-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?= $complaint['id'] ?>" data-target="#complaintFeedbackModal">
                                                                    Rate
                                                                </button>
                                                            </td>
                                                        <?php } elseif ($role == 'FACULTY' && $complaint['feedback'] != NULL) { ?>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark text-warning border-0 shadow-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Feedback: <?= $complaint['feedback'] ?>">
                                                                    <?php
                                                                    for ($j = 0; $j < $complaint['rating']; $j++) {
                                                                        echo '☆';
                                                                    } ?>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        <?php } elseif ($role == 'FACULTY') { ?>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <button class="btn  m-auto shadow-sm disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Can only give feedback after finishing work" style="text-decoration: line-through;">
                                                                    Rate
                                                                </button>
                                                            </td>
                                                        <?php } ?>

                                                    </tr>

                                            <?php $sno = $sno + 1;
                                                }
                                            } ?>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- table end -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is my insert jquery

```
    <script>
        //Add new complaint
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#complaint").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "complaint-data.php",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(response) {

                        $('#complaint')[0].reset();

                        $('#newComplaintModal').modal('hide');
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Succesfully Added!',
                            timer: 2000
                        });
                        $("#zero_config").load(" #zero_config");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.error("Error: " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But after i insert a new complaint it mess up the table structure. Also there is a black shade inside the table. I have to manually refresh the page in order for it to work.

Included files

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!-- Favicon icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
<title>SRMS</title>
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="assets/libs/jquery-steps/jquery.steps.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/libs/jquery-steps/steps.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
<link href="dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- table -->
<link href="assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!-- All Jquery -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/extra-libs/sparkline/sparkline.js"></script>
<!--Wave Effects -->
<script src="dist/js/waves.js"></script>
<!--Menu sidebar -->
<script src="dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
<!--Custom JavaScript -->
<script src="dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
<!-- this page js -->
<script src="assets/libs/chart/matrix.interface.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/chart/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/flot/jquery.flot.crosshair.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/chart/jquery.peity.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/chart/matrix.charts.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/chart/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/flot.tooltip/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/chart/turning-series.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/pages/chart/chart-page-init.js"></script>
<script src="assets/extra-libs/multicheck/datatable-checkbox-init.js"></script>
<script src="assets/extra-libs/multicheck/jquery.multicheck.js"></script>
<script src="assets/extra-libs/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> -->

<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script>
    /****************************************
     *       Basic Table                   *
     ****************************************/
    $('#zero_config').DataTable();
</script>
```

I tried refreshing the table body only. When i do that there is no dark shade which usually occurs when i refresh the table entirely. But the pagination still not working. I tried the ajax.reload() but it is not working either. I checked for some unclosed brackets but i can't find any. At the beginning I had some modals inside the table structure. I thought it might be affecting the structure, but it is not either.

Comment: *I checked for some unclosed brackets* - check the browser console for errors.  The browser (or any basic IDE) will be able to tell you if brackets are missing (though sometimes the error isn't clear, there will still be an error).

Comment: Without looking in detail at all that php code (on a js question, include the *rendered* HTML).   There are two issues that jump out:  `$("#zero_config").load(" #zero_config");` and `$('#zero_config').DataTable();` - in the startup you *convert* your table to a [tag:jquery-datatable] - from that point you should only use the datatype API, do not change the html directly.  So when you reload using `$().load()` you are removing the datatable.  You could just call `$('#zero_config').DataTable();` again after your .load() or use the datatables API to refresh the data.

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the page, it's best to use datatable serverside https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side